# How to make shortcut to external apps in PortableApps.com Platform?

Tags: portable-apps

I have few portable apps which are not available in [PortableApps.com's](http://portableapps.com/) .paf.exe format, and I'd like to be able to launch them from [PortableApps.com Platform's](http://portableapps.com/download) menu.

**How can I add shortcut to external app in my PortableApps.com Platform?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Can I add a shortcut to an external app in the PortableApps.com Platform?

Yes, you can. See the following instructions.

> Portable Apps is an open-source application launcher that allows you
>   to run programs right from your flash drive. The launcher comes with a
>   full suite of applications pre-installed. **If you want to include your
>   own applications, however, you must manually add them to the launcher**.
>
> **Instructions**
>
> 1. Insert the flash drive on which Portable Apps is installed.
> 2. Browse to the folder that Portable Apps was installed in using Windows Explorer. The folder should be named PortableApps and will
>      likely be in the root of your flash drive.
> 3. Right-click a blank space, select "New" and click "Folder."
> 4. Type the name of the application you wish to add to the launcher as the new folder's name.
> 5. Copy the application and its associated files to your newly created folder.
> 6. Launch the Portable Apps menu.
> 7. Click "Options" and select "Refresh App Icons" to have your new application added to the menu.

Source [How to Add Your Own Apps to Portable Apps](http://www.ehow.com/how_7406314_add-own-apps-portable-apps.html)  by Robert Kingsley

Comment: Side note: your app may be placed in the wrong category. If you can't see it, search for the app name in at the top of the PortableApps menu.
Once you find it, right-click and select "categories" to re-assign your app.

I had MusicBee assigned to "Other" instead of "Music & Video" - took a few minutes to sort that out.